# communication between micro-services after completed some thing

Tags: microservices, saga

Let's say we have two microservices: `MeetingProposal` and `Meeting`.

Process of creating a meeting:

- To create a meeting, users should propose their request, after their request, we create a proposal and show it to the admin.
- If admin accepts the proposal then we should change the status of proposal to `accepted` and also create a meeting in the **meeting** microservice.

**Question:**
How we should connect these two processes to each other (`after proposal accepted` => `create meeting automatically`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **business processes management**, **long running flows**, **sagas**, or similar([see this](https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/how-to-implement-long-running-flows-sagas-business-processes-or-similar-3c870a1b95a8))

We should use some orchestration engines like [Cadence](https://github.com/uber/cadence) or [Netflix Conductor](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/) or any other orchestration engine.